# Im SSHing into a Rails site, when I boot the rails server everything loads okay, but I'm getting the "webpage not available" in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh

I'm logged into a remote server with SSH, that is hosting a rails app. I checked in the console what environment was on and it returns 'development.' I launch the server and everything loads okay, but when I try and view the site with localhost:3000 or 0.0.0.0:3000 etc etc I get the "webpage not available" error, where could the server be displaying the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost is only accessible *from* the localhost -- you'd have to be running the browser **ON** the remote server.

Comment: More specifically, you have to *point* the browser at the remote server.

Comment: What do I add to the URL that I use to login?

Comment: If your server only has an IP address, you'd use that -- http://w.x.y.z:3000 if you're running the server using ```rails s``` or with the domain that points to that server if you've got a domain name.